# information regarding can, can-dev kernel modules on Debian GNU/Linux 10 (buster) Linux 4.19.94-ti-r42

Tags: kernel-modules, canbus

I seem to be missing a couple of kernel modules. Specifically, `can` and `can_dev`.
The modules don't load when I run `modprobe can` or `modprobe can-dev`.

The reason for this I believe is because the modules are not in the directory

```shellsession
[/lib/modules/4.19.94-ti-r42/kernel/drivers/net/can]$ ls
slcan.ko.xz  spi  usb  vcan.ko.xz
```

The only loaded CAN module is `can_raw`, which seems to work fine with SocketCAN.
My problem is that I am trying to use [ValueCAN](https://intrepidcs.com/socketcan-vcan4/) which depends on the 2 modules.

I tried downloading the kernel and when I ran `menuconfig`, I don't see the CAN modules.

I have no idea how to proceed.

The following is menuconfig selections.

```
--- CAN bus subsystem support   

     <M>   Raw CAN Protocol (raw access with CAN-ID filtering) 
      <M>   Broadcast Manager CAN Protocol (with content filtering)
      <M>   CAN Gateway/Router (with netlink configuration)      
            CAN Device Drivers  --->
    
      <M> Virtual Local CAN Interface (vcan)                        
      <M> Virtual CAN Tunnel (vxcan)                             
      <M> Serial / USB serial CAN Adaptors (slcan)               
      <M> Platform CAN drivers with Netlink support              
      [*]   CAN bit-timing calculation (NEW)                     
      < >   Support for Freescale FLEXCAN based chips (NEW)      
      < >   Aeroflex Gaisler GRCAN and GRHCAN CAN devices (NEW)  
      < >   TI High End CAN Controller (NEW)                     
      < >   Bosch C_CAN/D_CAN devices (NEW)  ----                
      < >   Bosch CC770 and Intel AN82527 devices (NEW)  ----
      < >   IFI CAN_FD IP (NEW)                                  
      < >   Bosch M_CAN devices (NEW)                            
      < >   Renesas R-Car CAN controller (NEW)                   
      < >   Renesas R-Car CAN FD controller (NEW)                
      < >   Philips/NXP SJA1000 devices (NEW)  ----              
      < >   Softing Gmbh CAN generic support (NEW)               
            CAN SPI interfaces  --->                             
            CAN USB interfaces  --->                             
            [ ] CAN devices debugging messages (NEW)
```

Comment: The modules (vcan), (vxcan) and (slcan) show up, but the other modules don't have a name assoctiated with them, so it was difficult to tell which one is can-dev and which one is can.

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://www.kernelconfig.io/config_can?arch=x86&kernelversion=4.19.279) shows the modules and what I would need to select in order to create them.
I searched for both can.ko and can-dev.ko

```
    Platform CAN drivers with Netlink support
    modulename: can-dev.ko
    configname: CONFIG_CAN_DEV
    Linux Kernel Configuration
    └─> Networking support
    └─> CAN bus subsystem support
    └─> CAN Device Drivers
    └─> Platform CAN drivers with Netlink support
    
    CAN bus subsystem support
    modulename: can.ko
    configname: CONFIG_CAN
    Linux Kernel Configuration
    └─> Networking support
    └─> CAN bus subsystem support
```

From what I gather, I will have to recompile the kernel to create the modules.

Comment: Welcome to the site. Unfortunately, it is unclear whether your post is attempting to solve the original question, is a comment on the question, or a related new question. Please edit it to make the intention clearer.